# Is there an index like function in VBA which can return multiple column data on perfect match?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks with data like this:

[image: Raw]
[image: Master Key File]

As seen, column A is my unique key to map the 2 workbooks. The values i want to populate are the "TBD" in the Raw file (image1). So i'm looking for key 11x in Master File and get values for column B, C & D (assembly, sub and part) for that key.

I "tried" `match` func but couldn't figure the destination to copy the search value and my code only returns one value at a time anyways...

```
for R = 2 To lastrow
    y=application.match(worksheet2.cells(R,1), worksheet2.range("A:A"),0)
If not application.isnumber(y) Then
    worksheet2.cells(x,1).copy destination:=worksheet1.cells(**?????????**)
```

So, can i return all three column values using one index match formula? If not how can i write the search function in VB? Please help.

Comment: Use `Find` and `FindNext` to loop through all recurrences of a criterium. Code is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext

Comment: @BigBen my intention was to return all 3 column values using my key, say 11x. the index match returns 1 value, example just the "Bus": for key 11x. Of course i can do this for other 2 columns as well, but it's getting tedious.

Comment: Can you please show how the result should look like?

Comment: @DariuszSokol - the result is to make image1 as image2, i.e replace all "TBD" cells with their corresponding values from master file (or image 2 above).

Comment: @BigBen - isn't that the same formula i used above? sorry i couldn't get your comment. I was more asking how i can use Find/FindNext/match functions in a `for` loop in VBA and return values for that key

Comment: @BigBen - yes I edited the question

Comment: If you have `O365` with the `FILTER` function, and are OK with creating a new table, you can do this with worksheet functions.

Answer (score 1):

This code is executed within the workbook where the search is initiated.

```
Private Sub CmdBtn_Click()
On Error GoTo workbookErr
Dim WbMaster As Worksheet: Set WbMaster = Workbooks("MasterWorkBook.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim WbCopyTo As Worksheet: Set WbCopyTo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim rangeWbCopyTo As Range, rangeWbMaster As Range
Dim cellWbCopyTo As Range, cellWbMaster As Range
Dim i As Integer

With WbMaster
    Set rangeWbMaster = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
With WbCopyTo
    Set rangeWbCopyTo = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
End With

For Each cellWbCopyTo In rangeWbCopyTo
    For Each cellWbMaster In rangeWbMaster
        If cellWbCopyTo.Value = cellWbMaster.Value Then
            For i = 0 To 2
                cellWbCopyTo.Offset(0, 1 + i).Value = cellWbMaster.Offset(0, 1 + i).Value
            Next i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cellWbMaster
Next cellWbCopyTo
Exit Sub
workbookErr:
MsgBox "Open MasterWorkBook before executing the search.", vbCritical
End Sub
```

Comment: I think by convention i is not declared with a variable type when used in a For loop. This way i is used in the loop and disposed of in memory after the loop finishes.

Comment: @technoman23, there's no such convention in VBA. Instead in VBA you can act two ways: 1) declare `Option Explicit` and be forced to explicitly declare all variables 2) don't use `Option Expicit` and have the VBA interpreter assume all unexplictly declared variables as of `Variant` type

Comment: @DariuszSokol, you want to 1) explicitly qualify all your ranges up to their worksheet and workbook parents (see.: `Cells` and `Rows.Count` in those first two setting ranges lines) 2) put an `Exit For` statement  after `Next i` not to keep searching in `rangeWbMaster` after one match

Comment: @HTH i have updated the snippet in accordance to your suggestions. Very good idea to exit the inner loop. Thanks it's much appreciated.

Comment: @HTH I looked into this and it turns out vba has a very strange scope. It does not have block level or loop level scoping. Which means variables declared inside a loop are accessible within the containing function or sub by default. This is in contrast to C#, another .NET language. This is also testable by attempting to access the variable immediately after the loop finishes.

Comment: @technoman23. VBA is not a .NET Language. The loop variable is accessible after the loop as well as before it: if you 1) chose not to use `Option Explicit`, either it has been explicitly declared (-> scoped as per the declaration) or it has been not (-> implicitly dimmed as of `Variant` type and sub scoped); 2) chose `Option Explicit` -> you must have declared it -> scoped as per the declaration